# Cambiar el formato en que exporto un csv desde Node Js

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Buen día,

Soy nuevo en Nodejs y estoy teniendo un problema para esperar por requests, tengo un código en el cual hago llamadas a una URL para obtener datos dentro de un loop (for) en el cual defino la pagina a la que llamo, el problema es que las requests tardan distinto tiempo en llegar y por tanto al no esperarse entre ellas, llegan en distinto orden rompiéndome el código, no he encontrado la manera de esperar que una request termine antes de empezar la siguiente, probé con await y con promises pero probablemente lo haya utilizado mal.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [ask]. Deberías agregar el código de lo que estás intentando, además mostrar el error que te da tu implementación y el resultado esperado. Puedes leer [mcve] para que entiendas un poco más la forma de realizar las preguntas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probablemente tengas que utilizar promises y la funcion Promise.all(listaPromises), la cual termina cuando todas las promises de listaPromises terminaron. Tené en cuenta que listaPromises es un iterable, por lo cual puede ser un array o cualquier otra forma de iterable.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Sin embargo la pregunta no es clara, y las respuestas a la misma se basarían en opiniones, además de ser una pregunta muy amplia, ya que no hay código para saber la forma en que el autor está implementado su solución. Te invito a leer [answer]. Y en todo caso esperar hasta tener la reputación necesaria para realizar comentarios. Saludos